# batch to url encode using replace method

Tags: windows, batch-file, urlencode

Cant seem to find a way to encode a url using a batch so i remember to make a replace.

The problem is that the url encode uses % and i think thats the problem for my code not to be working.

```
ex: SET varr=!varr:#=%23!
```

Anyone have an idea how to do this?
Full code bellow (without some of the url encode because of stack lenght issues)

```
        @ECHO OFF
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    SET varr={"temRazs":{"es":{"ted":[],"items":[{"cod":"1234567","nam":"patrick","where":"ggf","tip":"P",false,"shared":false,"verid":"1064.0ada83b2-3a3f-46a3-95b7-35b8c9ed8f24","className":"myclassname"}}}
        SET varr=!varr:"=%22!
        SET varr=!varr:#=%23!
        SET varr=!varr:$=%24!
        SET varr=!varr:%=%25!
        SET varr=!varr:&=%26!
        SET varr=!varr:'=%27!
        SET varr=!varr:(=%28!
        SET varr=!varr:)=%29!
        SET varr=!varr:*=%2A!
        SET varr=!varr:+=%2B!
        SET varr=!varr:,=%2C!
        SET varr=!varr:-=%2D!
        SET varr=!varr:.=%2E!
        SET varr=!varr:/=%2F!
        SET varr=!varr:0=%30!
        SET varr=!varr:1=%31!
        SET varr=!varr:9=%39!
        SET varr=!varr::=%3A!
        SET varr=!varr:;=%3B!
        SET varr=!varr:<=%3C!
        SET varr=!varr:==%3D!
        SET varr=!varr:>=%3E!
        SET varr=!varr:?=%3F!
        SET varr=!varr:@=%40!
        SET varr=!varr:A=%41!
        SET varr=!varr:[=%5B!
        SET varr=!varr:\=%5C!
        SET varr=!varr:]=%5D!
        SET varr=!varr:^=%5E!
        SET varr=!varr:_=%5F!
        SET varr=!varr:`=%60!
        SET varr=!varr:z=%7A!
        SET varr=!varr:{=%7B!
        SET varr=!varr:|=%7C!
        SET varr=!varr:}=%7D!
        SET varr=!varr:~=%7E!
        SET varr=!varr:,=%B4!
        SET varr=!varr:µ=%B5!
        SET varr=!varr:»=%BB!
        SET varr=!varr:¼=%BC!
        SET varr=!varr:½=%BD!
        SET varr=!varr:¿=%BF!
        SET varr=!varr:À=%C0!
        SET varr=!varr:Á=%C1!
        SET varr=!varr:Â=%C2!
        SET varr=!varr:Ã=%C3!
        SET varr=!varr:Ä=%C4!
        SET varr=!varr:Å=%C5!
        SET varr=!varr:Æ=%C6!
        SET varr=!varr:Ç=%C7!
        SET varr=!varr:È=%C8!
        SET varr=!varr:É=%C9!
        SET varr=!varr:ô=%F4!
        SET varr=!varr:õ=%F5!
        SET varr=!varr:ö=%F6!
        SET varr=!varr:÷=%F7!
    echo 1
    pause
    set urll=!varr!)     
    echo %urll% 
    Pause
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to double the percent symbols.

Comment: You should also enclose all your `SET` commands in double quotes. `SET "varr=!varr:|=%%7C!"`

Comment: Are you looking to encode all 256 extended ascii characters?

Comment: Also you only need to encode [reserved characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and `%`.

Comment: @zett42, you make a good point on the percent symbol.  They are encoding the percent symbol but that actually needs to be the very first character that needs to be encoded otherwise it will try to encode all the previous percent symbols that have been encoded.

Comment: Good point to booth of you, thanks :)

Comment: make the recomended changes and still got error in SET "varr=!varr:~=%%7E!"
SET "varr=!varr:!=%%21!"
SET "varr=!varr:==%%3D!"

Comment: When i run  it gives back varr%3A*=%2A